# Can I change my affiliation after re-submitting the manuscript before acceptance?

Tags: affiliation

One manuscript has been submitted after the 1st revision, and I am the 4th author. I didn't contribute to the work initially, so my name was not there on the first submission. Whereas during addressing comments from reviewer, I contributed and hence my name added as 4th author during re-submission. However, there is a mistake about my affiliation in the re-submitted manuscript. The manuscript is yet to be accepted. If it will accept, then can I change my affiliation? If so, in which stage I can do that? Is it possible during proof-reading? I am afraid if we inform the editor about this before acceptance, he won't take it well and reject the manuscript due to this silly mistake. As this particular query is not available in the 'Guide for Authors' or anywhere in the journal, I can't understand what should I do.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Affiliations change, sometimes in the middle of submission. The "author information" side does not affect the "accept on the merits" side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can usually change your affiliation after acceptance, during the proofs stage.

There's no need to inform the editor that there is an error in your affiliation, but you should inform them that there is another author. If they're paying attention, they should notice themselves, and investigate (because extra authors is a potentially fraught thing that need to be clarified). If you inform the editor, then you can head off the editor's request for clarification if/when they discover it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely change it later on. Most important thing is that you will need to be on top of this with the main (first/last) author who is taking care of the submission and proofreading. It's rare that the middle authors concern themselves with the final stages of getting the manuscript ready for publication, so make sure you see a next version of the manuscript where it is correct or send them this information ASAP and then again when you hear the manuscript is accepted for publication etc.