# Changing author's affiliation after a paper is submitted

Tags: ieee

I worked on an article when I was with University X . Now I am with University Y.  I submitted the article in IEEE access with University Y email and affiliation as corresponding author. However, with University X affiliation as corresponding author I would receive some benefits in terms of article processing charges since the University X is in their list. With university Y affiliation I will have to pay the APC from my own pocket. So I want to change my affiliation. If my paper comes with major/minor revision, will I be able to change my university affiliation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change my affiliation after re-submitting the manuscript before acceptance?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/193741/can-i-change-my-affiliation-after-re-submitting-the-manuscript-before-acceptance)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can even change your affiliation at the galley stage.

Comment: I have edited the question I hope its now more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no problem.  The only thing you cannot change is the list of authors, and order.   Other than that, affiliation can be updated.  You may need to note that the work was done when you were at your previous institution.

Comment: Even the authors *can* be changed, you will just need to explain why. For example, the revisions might involve running additional experiments with new collaborators, in which case it would be fine to add them to the paper.

Comment: @avid in my discipline that's not allowed because there have been cases where authors sell co-authorship to others upon receiving a revision.

Comment: Changing authorship depends on the journal and the discipline. Some journals allow, some don't. In any case, the reason should be provided (taking note of the rule/norm of authorship)

Comment: yes I worked on the article when I was at my previous institution. Do I need to email the editor for change of affiliation?

Comment: @user7341333 no.  There will be opportunities for you to update your affiliation at a later time, e.g., upon receiving a recommendation or if it's already accepted, then you can ask for the change when they show you the galley proof.